# React native animation for fading one word into another

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to find a way to fade "word1" into "word2" when a button is clicked using react native animation.

The way I'm approaching it now is by using absolute positioning word1 and word2 in the same location, and via an animation reducing/increasing opacity of each word. I increase opacity of word1 while simulataneously decrease opacity of word2, and vice versa.

This works great on IOS, but theres an issue on Android - it seems like `Pressable` don't really work in android when using absolute positioning: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27232

```
  const englishTextAnim = useRef(
    new Animated.Value(deviceLanguage === "en" ? 1 : 0)
  ).current;
  const spanishTextAnim = useRef(
    new Animated.Value(deviceLanguage == "es" ? 1 : 0)
  ).current;

...


            <Pressable
              onPress={() => {
              }}
              style={styles.nextButton}
            >
              <Animated.Text
                style={[styles.nextButtonText, { opacity: englishTextAnim }]}
              >
                Next
              </Animated.Text>
              <Animated.Text
                style={[styles.nextButtonText, { opacity: spanishTextAnim }]}
              >
                Siguiente
              </Animated.Text>
            </Pressable>

...

  nextButton: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  nextButtonText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
```

Are there any other ways of getting the same effect (fading one word into another when a button is clicked)?

Comment: just code this animation in CSS

Comment: @BartłomiejStasiak this is a React Native question, CSS won't help.

Comment: @sgonzalez the thread you linked says the issue is fixed in RN 66, are you using an earlier version?

Comment: @Abe Unfortunately we are using expo, and the latest version only supports React Native 0.64.3.

Comment: It looks like the absolute positioning is on the text and not the Pressable itself, which I think should work - what's the problem you're having? Is it not responding to presses?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't respond to presses on Android. If I remove the absolute positioning, the pressable works again, but I don't get the desired visual effect.